# Android: Strikethrough text in LIstView

Tags: java, android

I have a simple `ListView`, where a user must strike-through text by clicking on an item. 
But I don't have an idea how can I do it.

I found this method but it doesn't work in ListView:

```
setPaintFlags(text.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: can you show us what you have tried? and where?

Answer (score 0):

Its really hard to help you without you showing much code. What I can do is give you some easy hints. Wherever your `TextView` is located in your adapter, set a `View.onClickListener`. Assuming you are using Eclipse it will autofill it for you at a certain point. If not just search for click listeners on google and you get pretty quick results. Then in the listener's `onClick` method you actually add the above code that you included:

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

That should be enough for you to go on. Good luck :)